# How to add a row to a DataFrame (or CSV) in Pandas with DateTime Index

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting data every minute through an API call. Now I want to add this data to a CSV file. The data should update to the CSV after it gets new data.

I am using this code:

```
num_points = 1

df_setup = ig_service.fetch_historical_prices_by_epic_and_num_points(epic, resolution, num_points)
df_setup_prices_ask = df_setup['prices']['ask'] 
panda_df = pd.DataFrame(df_setup_prices_ask)
time.sleep(60)

while True:
    stream_close_price = ig_service.fetch_historical_prices_by_epic_and_num_points(epic, resolution, num_points)
    df_last_close = stream_close_price['prices']['ask'] 
    
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(df_last_close)
    
    combined_data = pd.concat([panda_df,df_test], axis=1)
    
    combined_data.to_csv('data.csv')
    
    
    print(df_last_close)
    
    time.sleep(60)
```

However I can't figure out how to get this working. If I use the code above I get following output (only the "newest" data gets saved to the CSV):

```
DateTime,Open,High,Low,Close,Open,High,Low,Close
2022-09-21 14:34:00,143.992,143.995,143.99,143.992,,,,
2022-09-21 14:36:00,,,,,143.977,143.978,143.975,143.978
```

Now when I use .join using this code:

```
combined_data = panda_df.join(df_test)
```

which give this error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], dtype='object')
```

Now I of course tried `combined_data = panda_df.join(df_test, on = 'DateTime')`
However this throws the key error for DateTime

Next up I tried using merge with this code which does not work because it only returns an empty CSV:

```
DateTime,Open_x,High_x,Low_x,Close_x,Open_y,High_y,Low_y,Close_y
```

Also I know that there is probably an easier way than doing a call to create a df to use as a base to join but I haven't figured that out.

Comment: Forgot the Code for merge I tried using this:     combined_data = pd.merge(panda_df, df_test, left_index = True, right_index = True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like my last comment explained I found a workaround where I just save the csv at the end of while function instead of saving and loading the first dataframe:

```
stream_close_price = ig_service.fetch_historical_prices_by_epic_and_num_points(epic, resolution, num_points)
df_last_close = stream_close_price['prices']['ask'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(df_last_close)

time.sleep(60) 

while True:

stream_close_price = ig_service.fetch_historical_prices_by_epic_and_num_points(epic, resolution, num_points)
df_last_close = stream_close_price['prices']['ask'] 

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_last_close)
    
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=0)
    
    print(df)
    
    df.to_csv('data.csv')
    
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#...
panda_df = pd.DataFrame(df_setup_prices_ask)
panda_df = panda_df.reset_index(names='DateTime') #add this <<---
panda_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index=False) #don't forget index=False otherwise will not work

while True:
    prevous_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

    stream_close_price = ig_service.fetch_historical_prices_by_epic_and_num_points(epic, resolution, num_points)
    df_last_close = stream_close_price['prices']['ask'] 
    
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(df_last_close)
    df_test = df_test.reset_index(names='DateTime')  #add this <<---

    combined_data = pd.concat([previous_df, df_test], axis=1, ignore_index=True) 
    
    combined_data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False) #don't forget index=False otherwise will not work
    
    
    print(df_last_close)
    
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It works partially. The output to the csv is as following: 

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
2022-09-22 07:31:00,145.197,145.238,145.197,145.237,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,145.197,145.238,145.197,145.237,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,145.28,145.281,145.26,145.274,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,145.272,145.278,145.257,145.274

So basically it now saves the prices/data which is nice. However now the date time index is missing for the following prices.

Comment: Also when loaded into a new DataFrame it yields following result

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
0 2022-09-22 07:41:00 145.243 145.252 145.231 145.238 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 145.243 145.252 145.231 145.238 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 145.253 145.284 145.25 145.262

As you can see the first prices are in the rows 1 -4 while the next prices are in row 5-8 with the next prices in 9 -12

Comment: When I set Ignore Index to false the output is as follows 
'DateTime Open High Low Close Open.1 High.1 Low.1 Close.1 Open.1.1 High.1.1 Low.1.1 Close.1.1 Open.1.1.1 High.1.1.1 Low.1.1.1 Close.1.1.1
0 2022-09-22 07:45:00 145.3 145.337 145.291 145.333 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 145.3 145.337 145.291 145.337 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 145.315 145.35 145.311 145.324 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 145.348 145.379 145.342 145.352'

Comment: So basically right now it combines the Dataframes by adding new columns when it should just add new rows

Comment: Okay so I am one step further:
Using axis = 0 in combined_data gives following output 

DateTime Open High Low Close
2022-09-22 07:59:00 145.551 145.676 145.546 145.674
NaN          145.551 145.676 145.546 145.674
NaN          145.668 145.742 145.618 145.727

So this now makes the concat function add rows instead of columns 
However now the Datetime Index of the following rows is NaN

Comment: When using index = True in .to_csv we get the following output 
Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 0.1 DateTime Open High Low Close
0 0 0 2022-09-22 07:59:00 145.551 145.676 145.546 145.674
1 1 2022-09-22 07:59:00 NaN 145.551 145.676 145.546 145.674
2 2022-09-22 08:00:00 NaN NaN 145.668 145.742 145.618 145.727

Where now a new Index is added for every new datapoint .....

Comment: Another interesting find when using    axis=0, join ='inner',  
I get following results: 
Unnamed: 0 Open High Low Close
0 0 145.806 145.834 145.780 145.782
1 1 145.772 145.806 145.712 145.754
2 2 145.786 145.820 145.745 145.791
3 2022-09-22 08:27:00 145.743 145.759 145.724 145.751
Where now the date time Index is only kept on the last added data

Comment: before while loop and before you save panda_df to csv, do this and tell me what you get : ```panda_df.columns```and ```panda_df.dtypes```

Comment: panda_df.columns returns this:
Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close'], dtype='object')
While types gives me this:Open     float64
High     float64
Low      float64
Close    float64
dtype: object

So I think it looks like date time is not recognized as an index

Comment: ok, inside the while loop, do the same for df_test: ```df_test.columns``` and ```df_test.dtypes```

Comment: @NikolasWeichert no datetime here is an index not a column. this is what caused the problems, do the same for df_test and tell me what you get

Comment: Khaled I found out the problem:

The Problem arises from either loading or saving the csv
When loading / Saving the csv the index Datetime gets lost and gets renamed to "unnamed:0" This is the problem because obv. you can't concat on the same index if they are not the same 
so i am currently trying to figure out how to load/save to csv correctly

Comment: I was able to recreate the problem with two random date time datasets downloaded from yfinance 
''
'load_data = pd.read_csv('datatest.csv')
combined_data = pd.concat([load_data, df_2], axis=0)
combined_data.to_csv('test_result_data')
combined_data

Comment: I understand the problem now. I updated the answer, test it and let me know

Comment: I tried your updated answer, unfortunately I am getting the Error 
TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
on panda_df = panda_df.reset_index(name='DateTime')

Comment: names not name: ```names='DateTime'``` instead of ```name='DateTime'```, I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply
Unfortunately same error persists:
TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'

Comment: ok, I think you need to update your pandas, also, try empty reset_index() : ```panda_df.reset_index()```

Comment: So I updated Pandas from 1.14 to 1.1.5 but the same issue with: TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'
still persists. 
What is interesting and might have something to do with the issue is that when I use empty reset_index() I get following result: 
                   Datetime      Open      High       Low     Close  index
0 2022-09-07 22:59:00+01:00   NaN
0 2022-09-07 22:59:00+01:00 0.0

where it now adds an extra index one with NaN and one with 0.0

Comment: Alright I found an answer which solves my problem but is more a workaround than an actual solution.
So, instead of saving to csv and then calling the first data frame, I just create the data frame and hold it then use the while function to concat the 2nd data frame. Afterwards I make df1 = combined data which I then continue to use in the 2nd, 3rd etc loop. I save only the combined data to the csv in the end

Comment: Also @khaled koubaa thanks a lot for your help your input was of great value ++

Comment: glad you did it . if you can upvote and click accept answer, it will be awesome